# Counting likes via parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, count, parse-platform

Okay so i'm fairly new to iOS programming, i have searched every to find some way to find some documentation on creating one, this  is what i could come up with but cant get it to work. can some one please point me in the right direction.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Likes"];
[query whereKey:@"activity" equalTo:@"like"];
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
 if (!error) {
    // display the count in a label
cell.likeLabel.text = ... 
} else {
// The request failed
}
 }];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What isn't working? What is it doing that you think isn't right?

Comment: Just a word of caution.  Counts are not optimized on Parse and comes with a lot of limits.  There is a limit on count operations that is significantly lower than general requests.  You will definitely hit it if your app gets some regular traffic.  The other problem is that the count will stop if it's going too high and you'll get a number less than the actual number of objects.  The best way I've found is to make an `afterSave` hook that keeps track of the count.  Hopefully they'll improve this feature in the future.

Comment: @Logan thank you for the clarification on how counts work on parse, as i said i am new to objective c and parse so every little bit helps,

Comment: No problem! I only know because I recently ran into the problem myself and had to readjust things!  Didn't want you to get stuck in the same boat I was :)

Comment: @Fogmeister, i am trying to count all the likes that a post has and return it to a label, but all i am getting is just my cell being returned with the default label.

Comment: so for your like system did you use a join table or just pointers to an array?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your prase tables structure. I'm not quite get purpose of

```
[query whereKey:@"activity" equalTo:@"like"];
```

does the code works without this condition?

and I suggest in future to use [query findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock... instead of count cos you got strict limits on count function executes. If you are firing this code on tableView with lots of likes counts you would be in trouble even with a few users online.